# .net core & .net framework in the same team

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

Our development team has many .net framework 4.6 projects (VS 2015).
We want to start a new .net core project to eventually deploy on linux.

We have installed VS 2017 and the .net core 2.0 preview.

But how can we reuse the existing library projects in this new one ?

We research but it is not clear for us :
 - we need to change the target of the old projects from ".Net Framework 4.6" to ".NetStandard 1.x" ? (and solve the incompatibility)
 - or we can use them like that ? (but how?)

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, you can not use .Net desktop libraries like they are, you have to rebuild them against .Net Core and probably spend some time 1) making your code to run with limited available facilities; 2) testing your code to ensure that it behaves in exactly the same way it did on original .Net. For example, again as far as I know, LINQ is using Expression and is compiled to IL in .Net, while in .Net Core it is interpreted. Which sometimes can be a noticeable difference.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov: .NET Core doesn't interpret expression trees as far as I'm aware... and as of .NET Core 2.0, desktop assemblies should be usable too, I believe - that's the plan.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm currently developing UWP software utilizing EFCore and the statement that LINQ is being parsed came from one of MS guys on EFCore github. Maybe it was true for the older versions, maybe it's only .Net Native specific, maybe I got something wrong. I'm not certain.
I hope that the plan becomes reality soon, we'd be more then happy to move our server side to Linux but our first attempts were too time consuming so we pushed this idea away, at least for now.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov: I can easily imagine that being true for UWP but not other platforms. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10470 suggests it's UWP...

Comment: @JonSkeet yeap, .Net Native issue, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft publishes official guidelines for the porting process: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/porting/

To summarize:

1. Deal with your dependencies (by migrating them), recursively
2. Retarget your projects. Applications move to .NET core, libraries move to .NET Standard, where possible.
3. Use some helpful tooling to verify your ports
4. Test

So, to share things between .NET Framework and .NET Core, your libraries should target .NET Standard, as much as possible. Otherwise, you could possibly share the code and have to do multiple builds - build once targetting .NET Framework and again targetting .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

You can use/reference your old projects only if you target Full Framework in your new projects (which is not the case if you are going to run them on Linux).

If you started with preview you should convert you old projects to .Net Core projects and either target .NET Core 2.0 Preview or NetStandard 2.0 Preview. If you are not going to reference/use your old projects outside your application it might be better to target .NET Core 2.0 Preview because it might provide more API than NetStandard 2.0 Preview.